# Open Asp.net MVC from Asp.net Website in One solution with same parent form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have one solution, in that, I have 2 projects.

1. Asp.net project

   Let say i have webform here Default.aspx
2. Asp.net MVC Project.

   Let say i have razor page here is DefaultMVC.cshtml

   Startup Project is Asp.net
   I want to Open MVC website in the same asp.net website, in the same default.aspx page.

   How can i do that.

   Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Host your two websites in IIS, then put an `Iframe` in your asp.net website with source pointing to the MVC web site

example:

```
<iframe name="Embedded Frame" src="http://your_server/your_controller/your_action" height="550px" width="750px" align="left" frameborder="1" marginheight="5px" marginwidth="5px"  scrolling="auto">
</iframe>
```